# display an image that was selected in another component using Angular with fireBase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, image, show

i'm trying to display a photo that i have chose in another component
here is my code
in traitement.ts

```
onselectedFile(event: any) {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e: any) => this.imgSrc = e.target.result;
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
            this._selectedImage = event.target.files[0];
        } else {
            this.imgSrc = "assets/images/placeholder.jpg";
            this._selectedImage = null;
        }
    }

public save() {


        this.submitted = true;
        this.validateForm();
        if (this.errorMessages.length === 0) {
            var filePath = `images/traitement/imgOrdonance${this._selectedImage.name.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')}_${new Date().getTime()}`;
            const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
            this.storage.upload(filePath, this._selectedImage).snapshotChanges().pipe(
                finalize(() => {
                    fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
                        this._selectedImage = url;
                        this.traitementService.insertImageDetails(this._selectedImage);
                    })
                })
            ).subscribe();
            this.saveWithShowOption(false);
        } else {
            this.messageService.add({
                severity: 'error',
                summary: 'Erreurs',
                detail: 'Merci de corrigé les erreurs sur le formulaire'
            });
        }
    }
```

and in my traitement.html

```
<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-6 content">
                        <div class="contentImage">
                            <p class="p-mb-2 p-mr-2" for="3">Image ordonnance</p>
                            <img class="p-mb-2 p-mr-2" [src]="imgSrc" width="200px" height="100px"
                                  (click)="fileUploader.click()">

                            <input  class="p-mb-2 p-mr-2" type="file" accept="image/*" #fileUploader
                                   id="file-upload" type="file"  placeholder="Image ordonnance" (change)="onselectedFile($event)"
                                   />
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

and this is my service traitement.service.ts

```
 imageDetailList: AngularFireList<any>;
    getImageDetailList() {
        this.imageDetailList = this.firebase.list('imageDetails');
    }

    insertImageDetails(imageDetails) {
        this.imageDetailList.push(imageDetails);
    }
```

i'm using firebase to store my images and in another component I want to list those file that I selected anyone please have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to display urls or data in another component is local storage.
You can use local storage to set your data by using specific keyword and then call that local storage data in another component